# Link to delete row php using pdo and oop

Tags: php, sql, oop, pdo

my case: after user login ... it will display in table what the book he has ... i added  delete link in side each book ... for example i clicked on the link delete in side Math book i want to delete it .. how i can do that please.
i get the books but when i click on delete link nothing happen.

this function display books when user login

```
public function getBooks($start = 0, $limit = 2)
{
    $sql_start = $start * $limit;
    $sql_limit = $limit;

    //SELECT loginUser.username, Library.nameOfBook FROM loginUser JOIN userBook JOIN Library ON userBook.user_id = loginUser.id AND userBook.book_id = Library.id WHERE loginUser.username="loay";
    $query = "SELECT Library.nameOfBook FROM loginUser JOIN userBook JOIN Library ON userBook.user_id = loginUser.id AND userBook.book_id = Library.id WHERE loginUser.username=:username LIMIT $sql_start, $sql_limit";
    $statment = $this->db->prepare($query);
    $statment->execute([
        ':username' => $this->username
        //,':start' => $start, ':limit' => $limit
    ]);
    $result = $statment->fetchAll();

   echo "<table border='1'>
    <tr>
    <th>Books</th>
    <th>Action</th>
    </tr>";
    foreach($result as $row){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['nameOfBook'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" ."<input type='submit' name='delete' value='Delete' method='post' " . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";

    if(isset($_POST['delete'])){

        deleteBooks($id1, $id2);
    }
}
```

And this function deleteBooks

```
  public function deleteBooks($id1, $id2)
```

{

```
    $id1 = $_GET['user_id'];
    $id2 = $_GET['book_id'];
    $query = "Delete FROM  userBook WHERE userBook.user_id=id1 AND userBook.book_id =id2";
    $statment = $this->db->prepare($query);
    $statment->execute([$id1, $id2]);
    $result = $statment->rowCount();
    $this->deleteBooks= ($result == "1");
    return $this->deleteBooks;
```

}

Comment: You need to bind your parameters in the execute function for the deleteBooks method

Comment: and then? @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs

Comment: well.. that's it, your function doesn't do anything other then prepare a query .. that's why nothing is happening

Comment: i try to bind parameters ... still not work .. please help me more

Comment: your link in the table doesn't pass either user id or book_id to the function. So you are just invoking it without any parameter. Your query will never know which book and for which user

Comment: @LelioFaieta  how i can solve this issue?

Comment: @husamalmasri by passing in function params then bind the params in the ->execute function

Comment: `onClick` is Javascript event trigger, i.e. it is on the client/browser side, while your `deleteBooks()` is server side of code.

Comment: @hcheung and how i can solve it ?

Comment: You have two choices, 1) learn how to write event handler and ajax to send the data from javascript client back to server; 2) create html form submission at your html (instead of using `onClick`) and handle the submitted data in your `deleteBooks()` function.

Comment: @hcheung  i edited my code please check now

Comment: I would suggest you learn the proper `<form>` tag with `action` and `method` attributes from [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp). On the `deleteBooks()`, if your form method is `POST`, then you should use `$_POST` instead of `$_GET`. Read the [form handling from W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp)

Answer (score -1):

First of all you have to add book.id on the link

`echo "<a href='?deleteBooks&id={$row['id']}' onClick=\"return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')\">Delete</a>"`;

After you click yes you will have a get request.
Not sure where delete function is called after but you can pass $_GET 
parameter on it `deleteBooks($_GET['id])`.
and the function it self 
`public function deleteBooks($book_id) {
    $query = "Delete FROM  userBook WHERE userBook.user_id=? AND userBook.book_id =?";
    $statment = $this->db->prepare($query);
    $statment->bind_param("ss", $user_id, $book_id);
    $statment->execute();
    // 
}`
You should store user_id on a session i guess.